# Bot Framework How to add title to confimation dialog

Tags: c#, chatbot, botframework

I am follow this [tutorial](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html) to build a chatbot.

My code work well on *Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator* but when test in *Facebook Messenger* it got issue here:

```
Is this your selection?
* Sandwich: Black Forest Ham
* Length: Six Inch
....
> no
What do you want to change? //Facebook Messenger stop and not display this line
 1. Sandwich(Black Forest Ham)
 2. Length(Six Inch)
> 2
```

Here the message Bot Framework:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Param [elements][0][title] must be a non-empty UTF-8 encoded string","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HfCTxxxx"}}
```

I debug with emulator and found that my bot return content with empty `Title`.

```
 "attachments": [
{
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
  "content": {
    "title": "",
    "text": "What do you want to change? ",
    "buttons": [
```

How to overide this card when user type `no`?

Thanks